# Commanding desktop cube to unfold causes freeze

Tags: drivers, compiz, cube

Whenever I enter the key command to unfold the desktop cube (configured in CCSM 0.9.5.92 on Ubuntu 12.04) with ANY command combination (so I'm not sure if this is the common cmnd-alt-down issue) doesn't simply cause CCSM to crash, it freezes up my entire computer. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: My suggestion is *don't use CCSM*.. Or at least **don't active those *special effects* that you know that will make issues**.

Comment: I appreciate the advice, but I'm hoping for a solution, not a work around. If not use CCSM, is there a similar program you would suggest? Thanks.

Comment: A program to create the cube effect without ccsm? No idea..

Answer (score 0):

If you install the latest video drivers (For me, gforce m8400GS on a reflowed HP dv9000) you may resolve this issue. I can use the desktop unfold on non-Nvidia chipsets.

I used the script from ubuntu Extreme (Google ubuntuextreme nvidia script). If I choose the option for the latest beta drivers (Nouveau) the unfold works. If I install the 3.04.43 (Latest as of this writing, listed as Nvidia-current) or any other version from Nvidia, it crashes... a hard lock up.

So if you aren't using nvidia, then maybe an open source driver from Nouveau will work.